# Отправка POST запроса.

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Учу wordpress. И тут возник вопрос, как создать POST запрос при нажатии на кнопку оформить заказ в woocommerce. Совсем новичок,отправьте, где почитать об этом.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал хуки. 
Создал плагин, с простеньким кодом.

```
function any_sender($order_id){
//any code
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'any_sender' );
```